# get cairosvg working in windows

Tags: python, gtk, cairo, pycairo

Trying to get this code working:

```
import cairosvg
import os

path = "D:/PyProjects/Bla/Temp"
os.chdir(path)

cairosvg.svg2pdf(url='Pic.svg', write_to='image.pdf')
```

but get errors along similar to this [post](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/issues/140):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/work/lean_python/pdf/other.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cairosvg
  File "D:\env_python352\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import surface
  File "D:\env_python352\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 24, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "D:\env_python352\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2')
  File "D:\env_python352\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 43, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2
```

The post mentions:

```
CairoSVG (the python library and bindings) needs Cairo (The C library, part of GTK+) to run. It appears you don't have it an it's headers installed on your system.
```

So I followed step 1 - 5 described [here](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php). I now have cairo header files in:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\cairo
```

I also installed pycairo recommended by another source:

```
pip install pycairo-1.15.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I still get the above errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just do not get cairosvg to work. I found an alternative way to transform an svg into a png using the svglib package.

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF, renderPM
import os

path = "D:/Bla/Temp"
os.chdir(path)

drawing = svg2rlg("Pic.svg")
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "Pic.png")
```

Comment: this doesn't work if svg has transparent background

Answer (score 11):

The following workaround works for me:

- install cairosvg (`python -m pip install cairosvg`)
- run `import cairosvg` in a script.
- if it works, you're set. otherwise (`OSError: no library called "cairo" was found`):
- get a copy of libcairo-2.dll

  - I did this by installing from `uniconvertor-2.0rc4-win64_headless.msi` https://sk1project.net/uc2/download/
  - then look for where `libcairo-2.dll` was installed to.
- say the path is `C:\path\cairo\dlls\libcairo-2.dll`
- in your script add to the top (before import cairosvg)

`import os
os.environ['path'] += r';C:\path\cairo\dlls'`

- `import cairosvg` should now succeed and work.

(Assumes you are running 64bit version of Python, otherwise use `win32_headless.msi`)

Comment: GIMP also uses libcairo-2.dll, so the path was `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\bin` for me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me! thanks =) Inkscape also uses libcairo-2.dll. `os.environ['path'] += r';C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin'`

Answer (score 3):

I adopted a different way but discovered in the process a fix that allowed `cairosvg` to work on Windows 11 and Python 3.10.  Even with the GTK3 Runtime Win64 installed the dll could not be loaded and generated an error.  This resolved the issue.  Add this code before `import cairosvg`.  Source of idea was jcupitt, https://github.com/libvips/pyvips:

```
    import os
    gtkbin = r'C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin'
    add_dll_dir = getattr(os, 'add_dll_directory', None)
    if callable(add_dll_dir):
        add_dll_dir(gtkbin)
    else:
        os.environ['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join((gtkbin, os.environ['PATH']))

    import cairosvg
    cairosvg.svg2pdf(url='banana-coloured.svg', write_to='image.pdf')
```

Comment: ```import os
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin")```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the path of `libcairo-2.dll` with the `ctypes.util`.
In my case, It was a directory of old software called `Graphviz`.

```
python
>>> import ctypes.util
>>> path = ctypes.util.find_library('libcairo-2')
>>> print(path)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\bin\libcairo-2.dll
```

After uninstalling `Graphviz`.

```
python
>>> import ctypes.util
>>> path = ctypes.util.find_library('libcairo-2')
>>> print(path)
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libcairo-2.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first install cairocffi package first using a built binary package, then install cairosvg. That will resolve the problem.

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: Note that this can be done with `pipwin`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73913080/120398

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:
I had GIMP for Windows installed in my Program Files folder.
I copied the bin folder in to cairo folder in the root of my folder and then added it to path before importing the cairo package in Python.

```
import os

folder_path = os.path.abspath("./cairo/bin/")

path_env_var = os.environ["PATH"]

if folder_path not in path_env_var:
    os.environ["PATH"] = folder_path + os.pathsep + path_env_var

import cairosvg
```