# cairosvg on Windows

Tags: python, svg, cairo

I'm trying to get cairosvg to work after installing it with pip, but I can't seem to get it to work. I don't want to install MSYS2 & GTK+, so I'm hoping the libraries should be enough (I have Graphviz). But here's what I'm getting:

```
>>> import ctypes.util
>>> path = ctypes.util.find_library('libcairo-2')
>>> print(path)
c:\MyPrograms\graphviz\bin\libcairo-2.dll
>>> import cairosvg
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\U021586\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from . import surface  # noqa
File "C:\Users\U021586\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 24, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
File "C:\Users\U021586\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2', 'cairo-gobject-2')
File "C:\Users\U021586\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 38, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2
```

Now, this question was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265677/get-cairosvg-working-in-windows), but was never properly answered.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!