# QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets error: No library called cairo was found

Tags: python, pyqt, widget, pyside

I've been trying to implement methods to add some shadow effects to some parts of the UI (i.e. the header and footer) and was told to import/install PySide (or PyQt) and QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets (note I have PyQt5/6 and PySide6 installed) However, setGraphicsEffects doesn't seem to work. In other words, it acts like there is no said function available. Not only that, but when I run it, it gives me an OS error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\OneDrive\Documentos\ProjectSICI\propiedadesmain.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import *
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from Custom_Widgets.Qss.SvgToPngIcons import NewIconsGenerator
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\Qss\SvgToPngIcons.py", line 22, in <module>
    import cairosvg
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import surface  # noqa isort:skip
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
            ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 44, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'    
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo-2.dll'
```

Here's the whole script of the file for reference:

```
import os
import sys

import csv
from propiedades import *


# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
# from PyQt5.QtGui import *
# from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from functools import partial

shadow_elements = { "left_menu","frame_3", "frame_5", "header", "frame_8"}

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            
            self.setMinimumSize(850,600)
            
            loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
            for x in shadow_elements:
                
                effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
                effect.setBlurRadius(18)
                effect.setXOffset(0)
                effect.setYOffset(0)
                effect.setColor(QColor(0,0,0,255))
                getattr(self.ui,x).setGraphicsEffect(effect)
            
            
            self.show()
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

AM I missing something? Does it have to do with QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets? Note that I'm using Python 3.11. I tried to use Python 3.12 but the PyQt6 tools aren't supported with it.

Comment: what is Custom_Widgets?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265677/get-cairosvg-working-in-windows

Comment: It's what I was told to use to import QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets by using Custom_Widgets.Widgets.

Comment: I went with the link that you recommended me but everytime I try to install uniconvertor-2.0rc5-win64_headless.msi, nothing happens...